# Get Weekends between two dates if present in php

Tags: php

Example: `$startdate = 01-Aug-2018`  and `$enddate =  04-Aug-2018`

so, it should return an array with key date and value day name

```
array(
    "04-Aug-2018" => "Sat"
)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far, or are you expecting us to write it for you?

Comment: Hasn't this been asked before? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51627778/write-a-function-to-return-weekdays-name-if-present-between-2-dates-in-php

Comment: @kerbholz Agreed; sock puppetry now in effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do what you need, though you might want to tweak it to fit your project.

```
<?php

$date = '01-Aug-2018';
$date2 = '07-Aug-2018';

$period = new DatePeriod(
    new DateTime($date),
    new DateInterval('P1D'),
    new DateTime($date2)
);

$weekends = [];
foreach ($period as $key => $value) {
    if ($value->format('N') >= 6) {
        $weekends[$value->format('d-m-Y')] = $value->format('D');
    }  
}

var_dump($weekends);
```

Comment: thank you if worked perfectly.